# How to check if two given b2Body objects are touching?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I know how to check for collisions in the update loop - but I'm in a position where I need to see if two bodies are touching or overlapping in box2D. I have pointers to these objects and I don't want to check while moving through update.

I am still learning Box2D so apologies if this is a dumb question. I have tried to solve this for an hour or so now but I'm not having any luck.

It looks like you can do this using `b2TestOverlap` or maybe `b2CollideCircles` (since the objects are b2CircleShapes). If either of these is the correct strategy can you get the shape from a given body, and what should I use as the transform values? If these aren't the way to go, **how can I check if two given b2Body objects are overlapping or touching**.

UPDATE: Here's the code that I got thanks to LearnCocos2D:

```
    -(BOOL)isTouchingCentre:(b2Body*)bodyToTest{
    //body is a b2Body object
        bool overlap = b2TestOverlap(body->GetFixtureList()->GetShape(), bodyToTest->GetFixtureList()->GetShape(), body->GetTransform(), bodyToTest->GetTransform());
        return overlap;

    }
```

Comment: You can use the contact listener to detect when they touch and when they stop touching, and use these events to update a list of what other bodies each body is currently touching. Then you can check the contents of the list at any time to see what other bodies each body is touching.

Comment: Hey again. Is this the simplest way, or does b2TestOverlap have merit?

Comment: It's the most efficient. I don't know that it's the simplest, but given that you posted a question here the other way probably isn't so simple either :) I think b2TestOverlap is mainly an internal function. About keeping a list of what other bodies are being touched, there is an example for C++ in the section titled "Preventing jumping depending on ground type" in this tutorial: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumpability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the details of b2TestOverlap but I would give it a try. You can get the necessary info from the bodies, assuming they only have one shape:

```
body->GetTransform();
body->GetFixtureList()->GetShape();
```